# How to set a color by default in R for all plot.default, plot or lines calls

Tags: r, colors, plot, default

to simplify my daily R interactions, I'd like to set up default colors for all my plots. For example, let's say I want to have all plots made with red lines (like in gnuplot...:-) )

So far, here is a snippet of my .Rprofile

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"), 
    function(...) 
        grDevices::X11.options(width = 14, height = 8, type = "Xlib", xpos = 600,     ypos = 30, canvas = "grey87"))

suppressPackageStartupMessages( require(Defaults) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( require(utils) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( require(graphics) )

setDefaults("plot.default",frame.plot=FALSE, type='l', col=2)
```

What I do here is the following:
when the `grDevices` package is loaded (by loading the `graphics` package), I call the `X11.options` with my prefered parameters: a wider box, light gray background, xlib calls (because I'm doing distant calls, and cairo in my current environment is just too slow (another problem to solve))
Then I silently load 3 packages, `Defaults`, `utils` and `graphics`. The second one is needed to avoid a `find` function error message.

Finally, the magic function `setDefaults` set-up 3 parameters to the scatter plot function `plot.default`. The 3rd parameter `col` is not a parameter of `plot.default` but one from the `par()` function.

But, doing a `setDefaults` call with `par` doesn't work either.

Any solution is welcome...

Comment: `?palette` .... and set defaults on `plot.xy` ...

Comment: (this is a little more complicated than I thought -- plot.xy has some wrinkles that make it work badly with setDefaults -- but I still think it's the right track)

Comment: Can't you just put `par(col="red")` in your .Rprofile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `"plot.new"` hook to set default `par` values each time a new graphics frame is opened. (The hook's workings are documented in `?plot.new` and `?setHook`)

In your case, just add this line to your .Rprofile:

```
setHook("plot.new", function() par(col = "red"))
```

Comment: yes !!!! That was so simple indeed. Many thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Hello Googl.., if you're parsing this page, here are the hooks to do in R to have nice graphics, thanks to the help of stackoverflow users:   `setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),  function(...) grDevices::X11.options(width = 14, height = 8, type = "Xlib", xpos = 600, ypos = 30, canvas = "grey87"))`  and then you can add this too:      `suppressPackageStartupMessages( require(Defaults) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( require(utils))
suppressPackageStartupMessages( require(graphics))
setHook("plot.new", function() par(col="red"))
setDefaults("plot.default",frame.plot=FALSE, type='l')`

Comment: Getting this from under the dust. I am trying this, but for some reason the red colour is only applied to the labels of my legend. Any ideas?

Comment: @BramVanroy -- Hmm. I've got no idea, and wouldn't be able to help without a reproducible example, since the code in my answer still works for me with something like `plot(rnorm(99))`.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters such as color are set on a per device basis, so when you close one device and create a new one all the parameters are set back to their default values.  To do this I would create your own device function that opens the device then sets the parameters, something like:

```
mydev.new <- function(...) {
  dev.new(...)
  par(col='red')
}
```

You could obviously replace `dev.new` with `x11` or something else, but this is probably the most portable.  Now you can open a new device using `mydev.new` and the default color will be set to red.

Further if you run the command

```
options(device=mydev.new)
```

Then when you don't have a graphics device open and you run a plotting command, your function will be the one run to open a new plotting device and so the default will be red in that case as well.  You could expand the `mydev.new` function (or whatever you want to call it) to set other options, take arguments, etc. for different cases you may want to work with.