# How to change default plot type from points to line in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot, default

I am working with timeseries with millions of points. I normally plot this data with

```
plot(x,type='l')
```

Things slow down terribly if I accidentally type

```
plot(x)
```

because the default is `type='p'`

Is there any way using `setHook()` or something else to modify the default `plot(type=...)` during an R session?

I see from  [How to set a color by default in R for all plot.default, plot or lines calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625931/how-to-set-a-color-by-default-in-r-for-all-plot-default-plot-or-lines-calls) that this can be done for `par()` parameters like 'col'. But there doesn't appear to be any points-vs-line setting in `par()`.

Comment: You might find the [defaults](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/) package useful?

Answer (score 7):

A lightweight solution is to just define a wrapper function that calls `plot()` with `type="l"` and any other arguments you've given it. This approach has some possible advantages over changing an existing function's defaults, a few of them [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073912/setting-function-defaults-r-on-a-project-specific-basis/9074338#9074338)

```
lplot <- function(...) plot(..., type="l")

x <- rnorm(9)
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
plot(x, col="red", main="plot(x)")
lplot(x, col="red", main="lplot(x)")
```

[image]

Comment: As long as there is no equivalent to par(plot.type='l'), this looks like the simplest and safest solution.

Comment: @JonathanCallahan -- Yeah, there's nothing in the `par` list that will let you set the plot type. In **lattice** graphics, you could prob. do the equivalent by changing the default for `panel.xyplot`, but that'd not be much better than using the **Defaults** library.